# Pywinauto Windows Exists but not Visible

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am automating a third party application for a personal project using pywinauto. 
Facing a weird issue where a pywinauto returns True for a dialog.Exist but the dialog is not actually visible. As a result, since the code returns True, further action on the  dialog fails. I believe application has cached the dialog or something else. Not sure how to handle this.

```
app = Application().connect(path = "D:/myapp/Trader.exe")   
existFlag = app.window_(title ="Trader - 23506").Exists(timeout =2) 
print existFlag  #Returns True
if(existFlag):
    app.window_(title ="Trader - 23506").Close()  #Fails
```

Here is the output

```
**True**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myauto.py", line 792, in <module>
    app.window_(title ="Trader - 23506").Close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 357, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 239, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'process': 12964, 'backend': u'win32', 'title': 'Trader - 23506'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Win32 applications can have existing windows that are not visible. To check visibility you can call this:

```
visible = app.window(title ="Trader - 23506").is_visible()
```

Or it might be a timing issue (if fails in ~50% cases or existing window disappears right after `.exists(...)` call). So another way to handle closing the dialog is:

```
dlg = app.window_(title ="Trader - 23506")
try:
    dlg.wait_not('visible', timeout=2)
except Exception: # or timings.TimeoutError
    dlg.close()
```

Comment: Not a timing issue. But your workaround and the is_visible() check helped to put a workaround something like this:  
dlg = app.window_(title ="Trader - 23506")
try:
 if (dlg.Exists() and dlg.wait_not('visible', timeout=1)):
  print("Dialog might exist but not visible")
except:
 print("Dialog Exists and Visible")
 print(traceback.print_exc())